# Expanding a div to fill the page

Tags: css

I'm creating a webpage where the content div should fill all of the screen. At the moment it shrinks to the amount of content.

The footer should be 'sticky' and sit at the bottom of the screen (imagine there's hardly any content).

I've got the footer bit sorted, I'm just struggling with the height of the content div. How do I go about making the content div fill up the entire screen?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
#wrap {min-height:100%;}
header {
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}
#main {
    background:yellow;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
#main {
    font-size:28px;
    overflow:none;
}
footer {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-50px;
    clear:both;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
</style>
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <header>
        This is the header
    </header>
    <div id="main">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a viverra mauris. Aenean eu facilisis enim. Cras laoreet diam at lorem euismod condimentum. Morbi diam nisi, eleifend id varius vitae, ultrices sed nunc. Aenean facilisis, arcu sed congue tempor, leo nisi convallis dolor, et malesuada velit tortor id neque. Nullam nec eros est, at hendrerit risus. Vivamus in sollicitudin elit. Vivamus id odio justo, eget condimentum elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis mauris massa, iaculis eu laoreet sit amet, suscipit nec dolor. Ut rutrum porttitor viverra. Proin convallis, turpis id varius varius, nisi nulla vulputate dolor, vitae mattis neque quam ac nulla. Fusce accumsan, urna nec vulputate imperdiet, tortor erat fringilla massa, nec convallis ligula risus vitae mauris. Vivamus sagittis pulvinar ipsum, bibendum congue purus gravida posuere.</p>
<!--
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non lorem id ante scelerisque malesuada id ut nibh. Duis massa erat, dictum hendrerit interdum ut, faucibus non lorem. Sed velit leo, pellentesque sit amet dapibus vel, vestibulum ac sem. Nulla a hendrerit risus. In sodales ultricies lorem at tempus. Fusce sed velit urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut mi nunc, et tristique ipsum. Cras lobortis augue eget enim sodales et sollicitudin turpis feugiat. Morbi a interdum felis. Donec porttitor nibh ut metus commodo et pulvinar dui pretium. Fusce pellentesque felis in metus vehicula feugiat.</p>
<p>
Duis suscipit nibh non leo venenatis tempor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce tincidunt sapien id purus tempus ac viverra sapien vulputate. Fusce eu tortor purus. Mauris sit amet diam a arcu hendrerit auctor. Mauris vel nunc nec leo gravida ullamcorper. Donec eu arcu nibh, eu feugiat lorem. Nunc euismod ligula nec est lobortis vehicula. Etiam feugiat lacus in nulla porttitor eu iaculis dui dictum. Nullam gravida enim in leo tempor euismod. Cras porttitor, neque at molestie egestas, metus nisl tincidunt lacus, non vestibulum metus sapien eu est. Mauris tempus mattis quam eu elementum. Curabitur tempor feugiat massa, sit amet tempor mauris fermentum ut. Nullam faucibus lobortis lectus, ac fermentum sapien venenatis eget.</p>
<p>
Nulla facilisi. Proin a lorem non justo gravida pharetra a at dolor. Phasellus vitae viverra purus. Nullam at tellus id orci ornare cursus. Maecenas velit ante, egestas eu auctor at, lacinia in massa. Morbi sit amet turpis a neque vestibulum pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut accumsan aliquet sodales. Praesent tortor turpis, vulputate quis bibendum eu, pharetra vestibulum nunc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum convallis, lorem ac consectetur volutpat, diam sem bibendum lectus, vitae sagittis eros odio eget urna. Sed ipsum nulla, interdum nec accumsan at, faucibus at est. Vivamus faucibus condimentum erat, id varius metus cursus non. Vestibulum ut justo fringilla enim pellentesque auctor pretium eget quam.</p>
<p>
Ut in urna quis turpis placerat volutpat. Integer vel tincidunt sem. Pellentesque semper venenatis vestibulum. Pellentesque pretium volutpat neque eu dignissim. Aenean consectetur, magna in hendrerit sodales, mauris libero ullamcorper lectus, in imperdiet enim odio quis sem. Donec sed tellus urna, non sodales massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus rutrum dolor nec sem gravida dignissim. Curabitur in ante leo. </p>
-->
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    This is the footer
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the content div is always the full page, then why bother with a div?  That's what the body is.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: The content div is going to be attached to JavaScript gesture events. The user will be able to interact with the content div, so unfortunately I can't use the body on this occasion.

Comment: So it's that #main div you want to scale up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the footer to

```
position: fixed
bottom: 0
left:0
```

This should do the trick positioning the footer sticky to the bottom. But if the body expands beyond the footer it could pose an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might already know this, but in order to make an element fit the height of the viewport, it, as well as every other ancestor element, needs to be 100% height.

You've already done this for body and html (which is good), but you need to do this for #wrap too. Min-height won't work for that. Then, you'll want to set your header to a percentage height too so that you can have the #main div fill up the rest of the viewport. Something like:

```
#wrap  { height: 100%; }
header { height: 10%; }
#main  { height: 90%; }
```

This should take care of filling up the viewport, since your html and body are already set to height: 100%;